# as.Date not converting character date to date in R

Tags: r

I am trying to convert a character date to date but result is somehow a double.

```
> x
[1] "2017-10-31"
> as.Date(x)
[1] "2017-10-31"
> as.Date(x) %>% typeof
[1] "double"

> as.Date(x,format="%Y-%m-%d") %>% typeof
[1] "double"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `?typeof`

> typeof determines the (R internal) type or storage mode of any object

Instead of `typeof`, check the `class`

```
library(magrittr)
as.Date(x) %>%
    class
# [1] "Date"
```

Also, can be checked with `inherits`

```
as.Date(x) %>%
   inherits('Date')
#[1] TRUE
```

#### data

```
x <-  "2017-10-31"
```